# Excel need to sum distinct id's value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I am struggling to find the sum of distinct id's value. Example given below.

```
Week TID    Ano    Points
1    111    ANo1    1
1    112    ANo1    1
2    221    ANo2    0.25
2    222    ANo2    0.25
2    223    ANo2    0.25
2    331    ANo3    1
2    332    ANo3    1
2    333    ANo3    1
2    999    Ano9    0.25
2    998    Ano9    0.25
3    421    ANo4    0.25
3    422    ANo4    0.25
3    423    ANo4    0.25
3    531    ANo5    0.5
3    532    ANo5    0.5
3    533    ANo5    0.5
```

From the above data i need to bring the below result. Could anyone help please using some excel formula?

```
Week    Points_Sum
1       1
2       1.50
3       0.75
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say "**sum of distinct id's value**"? All the IDs are different so I'm assuming you want to sum for each different "Ano"  within the week?

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A$2:A$17=F2,MATCH(C$2:C$17,C$2:C$17,0)),ROW(A$2:A$17)-ROW(A$2)+1),D$2:D$17))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

where `F2` contains a specific week number

Assumes that each "Ano" will always have the same points value

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient solution... but this array formula works:

```
= SUMPRODUCT(IF($A$2:$A$15=$F2,$D$2:$D$15),1/MMULT((IF($A$2:$A$15=$F2,$D$2:$D$15)=
  TRANSPOSE(IF($A$2:$A$15=$F2,$D$2:$D$15)))+0,(ROW($A$2:$A$15)>0)+0))
```

Note this is an array formula, so you have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing this formula instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

See working example below. This formula is in cell `G2` and dragged down.

[image]

Comment: Just modified the question, I want to consider Ano also when doing sum. Will this formula work for the edited one?

Comment: @Sathish No, how could it? My formula doesn't even show the ANo column because your original question did not rely on this information.